# Streaming raspberry pi camera via nginx-rtmp

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, rtmp

I have compiled nginx with rtmp, and I'm trying to use to it stream a raspberry pi camera over the network. I've done a lot of googling, and there are a lot of approaches, but none seem to work for me. So far, I have this:

```
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;

                application rtmp {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                        exec_static /usr/bin/ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format h264 -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 30 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec copy rtmp://localhost/rtmp 2>>/home/pi/test.log
                }
        }
}
```

I would have expected the stream from the camera to be available on `rtmp://pi_ip/rtmp`, but instead, the log file reports:

```
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 12021.310578, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 2000k tbc
[NULL @ 0x1ca35d0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'rtmp://localhost/rtmp'
rtmp://localhost/rtmp: Invalid argument
```

Presumably there is something wrong with ffmpeg command, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: How did you solve the problem?